# How to verify if KES is valid without needing to wait for the next minted block?

Tags: stake-pool

With reference to my previous question regarding [inconsistent reading of KES validity](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/2051/invalid-kes-signature-ocert-but-gliveview-shows-kes-is-valid) given by cardano-node and gLiveView, is there any way I could objectively verify KES validity without waiting for the next block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things you can verify:

- Current opcert counter is higher than previous counter on chain in a block created by your pool (you can use dbsync or query a public instance) - you already saw in your previous thread that expected OCert for your node was 6). Starting Vasil fork, it is expected that - upon rotation, your opcert counter is higher by *exactly 1*
- Expiry date of KES  (can query EKG or also just check gLiveView).
- Make sure your cert was derived using kes from your cold key using which pool was created.

Once each of above is verified, it's simply a matter of waiting for your next block to get the proof/assurance. The above are pretty much the only checks you can perform.

Comment: What if you haven't done any blocks yet? Mine is currently up to 9, no blocks done, and the cert instantly expires.

Comment: @Cyberience - "instantly expires" => That suggests you're likely not using right start period for KES (assuming you're verifying it correctly using right files and post node restart)

Answer (score 2):

Try the 2 commands below to see if they give you the info that you need.

1 - Cardano version 1.34.0 (and 1.34.1?) has a bug that does not show KES calculations correctly - this should be fixed in 1.35.0. Below is from 1.34.1 after I did a KES rotation earlier today.

```
$cardano-cli query kes-period-info --mainnet --op-cert-file op.cert

✓ The operational certificate counter agrees with the node protocol state counter
✓ Operational certificate's kes period is within the correct KES period interval
{
    "qKesNodeStateOperationalCertificateNumber": 14,
    "qKesCurrentKesPeriod": 505,
    "qKesOnDiskOperationalCertificateNumber": 15,
    "qKesRemainingSlotsInKesPeriod": 6783509,
    "qKesMaxKESEvolutions": 62,
    "qKesKesKeyExpiry": "2022-09-22T21:44:51Z",
    "qKesEndKesInterval": 558,
    "qKesStartKesInterval": 496,
    "qKesSlotsPerKesPeriod": 129600
}
```

2 - Try using the localhost HTTP `metrics` details via CLI - note your port number may vary:

```
$curl -s 127.0.0.1:12798/metrics | grep KES

cardano_node_metrics_operationalCertificateExpiryKESPeriod_int 567 
cardano_node_metrics_currentKESPeriod_int 505 
cardano_node_metrics_remainingKESPeriods_int 62 
cardano_node_metrics_operationalCertificateStartKESPeriod_int 505
```